# EHLO returns nothing with postfix initialized working on port 25

Tags: linux, email, postfix, netcat

So I reinstalled postfix several times because of different issues.
Turns out it starts well and seems to be working on port 25:

I make netstat -nltp | grep 25

```
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18383/master        
  tcp6       1      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      18383/master
```

Then nc -v -C localhost 25
And I get

```
Ncat: Version 7.40 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ::1:25.
```

I don't think this is ok since something about postfix should appear.
Anyways I make "EHLO something" and no message is returned.

Ok so here's my maillog

```
Sep 17 10:18:24 localhost postfix/smtpd[3238]: fatal: open lock file pid/inet.smtp: cannot open file: Permission denied
Sep 17 10:18:25 localhost postfix/master[2477]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 3238 exit status 1
Sep 17 10:18:25 localhost postfix/master[2477]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Sep 17 10:18:53 localhost postfix/postfix-script[3264]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Sep 17 10:18:53 localhost postfix/master[2477]: terminating on signal 15
Sep 17 10:18:57 localhost postfix/postfix-script[3346]: starting the Postfix mail system
Sep 17 10:18:57 localhost postfix/master[3348]: daemon started -- version 3.2.5, configuration /etc/postfix
Sep 17 10:19:04 localhost postfix/smtpd[3360]: fatal: open lock file pid/inet.smtp: cannot open file: Permission denied
Sep 17 10:19:05 localhost postfix/master[3348]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 3360 exit status 1
Sep 17 10:19:05 localhost postfix/master[3348]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

Comment: I confirmed your expectations.  Look at the postfix logs and see what's happening

Comment: @kenlukas sorry, I just posted the log. I just had to install postfix-perl-scripts. UPDATE: problem fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I ended up fixing it very simple:

Just run the following command:

```
setenforce 0
```

Source: https://adminf1.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/fatal-open-lock-file-pidinet-smtp-cannot-open-file-permission-denied/